# UPDATED: Relational (or NoSQL) Database Design

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema, relational-theory

#### **(Updated this question with more specifics. Decided on a Relational Database, and would love some comments on its design)**

This database holds assembly instructions data for shipbuilding, later use in a Augmented Reality Android application. The application asks the server (Node.JS) for the necessary files.

Simply put: **Work Packages** contain several **Parts** that must be mounted, each of these parts has the **Files** necessary needed by the  application.

[image: Database Structure]

- *Work Packages* depend on other *Work Packages* (WD_Dependencies), in the figure above, S1 depends on 1 and 2;
- *Workers* can be assigned a specific *Work Package*, if not, the return *Work Package* is a combination of matches between *Type* and *Department*.

## Update:

**(Open in new tab for better view)**

[image: Database Design]

The database is "divided" between the blueprint of a project, and the specific execution of that blueprint. This also allows for multiple executions of the same blueprint.

#### Questions:

1. Is this a good design? Dividing Blueprint and Projects?
2. Efficient SQL Query to recursive lookup all the dependencies of a *Work Package*?
3. Do you see any problems with the relationships or any redundancy?
4. Any comments or help are welcomed.

I understand this could be a broad/opinion question, but I have no experience with database of this size, and would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which of the two options is the best?

The relational design is clearly superior to the hierarchical design used in the NoSQL example.  A database schema designed using relational principles does not favor one access path over another.  Each table represents a real world entity type and through the use of relational algebra queries of arbitrary complexity can be constructed to answer not only current questions of the data but any future questions you think of that haven't yet been conceived.  A hierarchical schema imposes a single structure upon the data - in this case work packages contain other work packages, the worker, and the parts, and the files.  If you want to ask questions of the data not aligned with this single view it will be much more difficult if not impossible.  Furthermore, the relational model includes a data integrity component to ensure data is consistent with respect to rules declared to it approximating the real world, whereas systems, like a NoSQL system, using a hierarchical or network model do not provide these.

> Should a Work Package reference the above Work Packages, or the contrary is better?

The best way to implement this is to create a new table that represents the links between the parent and dependent work packages while leaving the work package table to represent the work packages themselves regardless of dependency.  This design does not mix work packages dependent on other work packages with work packages that are **not** dependent on others.  A key advantage of the relational approach is that a single structure with a single set of operators - relational tables and relational algebra - can easily represent a hierarchy or a network.  Network DBMS's require two types - a node and a link - with two distinct sets of operators, and thus twice the complexity.  A hierarchical DBMS can't represent a network correctly at all.  This is a key reason why the NoSQL systems available today can only address a narrow set of use cases.  [Fabian Pascal](http://www.dbdebunk.com/)'s book [Practical Issues in Database Management](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201485559), Chapter 7, gives an excellent overview of data hierarchies using SQL and I highly recommend it.

> There will be a substantial of reads, however the writes will be considerable less.

Another benefit of the relational approach is that the performance of the system can be managed to a great extent at the physical level without impacting the logical database schema used by applications to work with the data.  With the relational approach you can focus on the correct logical schema first and then in most cases let the DBA implement a correct physical design and infrastructure to best support the read heavy workload.  This is not the case in navigational systems where the programmer must specify the access paths directly in programs.

Comment: Regarding the dependency of the Work Packages. You are suggesting I create a 'separate table' (not connected to the Work Package table)
In a sense, a Table Dependencies: id_WP (PK) and id_WP_Dependency 
Correct? @todd-everett

Comment: That is right but it is connected to the work package table. If you think of work package dependencies as a hierarchy, then the work package table holds each node, and the new table, say work package dependency, holds the links. There would be two relationships between work package and the new work package dependencies table. One relationship would be the parent work package and the second relationship would be the dependent work package. By doing it this way the dependencies are cleanly separated from the work packages.

Comment: I am not sure I follow your logic. I thought I could just keep a separate table, basically mapping the the ID of a Work Package to the Work Package Dependencies. Taking S1 from the example, I would have (idWK, idWP_Dependecy) the records (WP_S1, WP_1) and (WP_S1, WP_2). I don't see the relation between this 'dependencies' table and the work package table. Could you clarify your answer for me please.

Comment: I am saying that S1, 1, and 2, are all just work packages.  So the work package table has 3 rows for S1, 1, and 2.  The work package dependency table has 2 rows - (S1, 1) and (S1,2).  The work package table is connected referentially to the work package table as both columns in the dependency table refer back to a valid work package.  In the row (S1, 1), S1 is the parent reference and 1 is the dependent reference, both referencing the work package table.  This is a basic many to many network.

Comment: One more question. Suppose I want all the work packages of B1. I have to recursively search the packages that have B1 as a parent, and the work packages that have that same one as parent, and so on and so on. This seems to be a heavy search, especially since I don't know how deep it can go. Despite having many records, the separate table idea, in which I map all the dependencies of one work packages seems to be more simple, am I correct?

Comment: Yes I would agree having a separate table for just work package dependencies is more simple, but not because of the search.  The search algorithm is the same regardless.  It is more simple instead because it is easier to express the logic of the queries and the data integrity constraints.  The beauty of the relational approach is that you don't have to worry about how to do the search.  You just declare the logic via SQL and the DBMS finds the best access path.  With NoSQL you have to write that search yourself.

Comment: Could I ask you to comment on my updated question? I would appreciate your advice and input.